# Check if command is ran in certain channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I currently have this as my command:

```
bot.on('message', function (message) {
  if (message.content == '!register') {
    message.member.send("Registered!");
    let memberRole = message.member.guild.roles.find("name", "Verified");
    message.member.addRole(memberRole);
  }
});
```

I want it so this command can only be ran in a text channel called registration (I have the channel id if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code if you only have one textchannel called `registration`:

```
bot.on('message', function (message) {
  if (message.content == '!register' && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'registration') {
    message.member.send("Registered!");
    let memberRole = message.member.guild.roles.find("name", "Verified");
    message.member.addRole(memberRole);
  }
});
```

If you have two textchannels called `registration`, I would check the ID of the channel. This can be done with this code:

```
bot.on('message', function (message) {
  if (message.content == '!register' && message.channel.id === 'YOUR CHANNEL ID') {
    message.member.send("Registered!");
    let memberRole = message.member.guild.roles.find("name", "Verified");
    message.member.addRole(memberRole);
  }
});
```

By the way, you don't have to use `message.member` to receive the **guild** object. You can simply do `message.guild`!