# Prohibition of the use of emojireact-role in third-party channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

how to make sure that the role when pressing the bell is give only in a certain channel? The code is below. Can also make that only administrators have the right to issue reactions with a bell that will issue a role. Help, pls.

```
var emojiname = [""];
var rolename=[" Notifications"];

client.on('message', msg => {

if(msg.content.startsWith("reaction" && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'information')){
    if(!msg.channel.guild) return;
        for(let n in emojiname){
            var emoji =[msg.guild.emojis.find(r => r.name == emojiname[n])];
                for(let i in emoji){
                msg.react(emoji[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});

client.on("messageReactionAdd",(reaction,user)=>{
    if(!user) return;
        if(user.bot)return;
            if(!reaction.message.channel.guild) return;
        for(let n in emojiname){
            if(reaction.emoji.name == emojiname[n]){
                let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == rolename[n]);          
            reaction.message.guild.member(user).addRole(role).catch(console.error);
        }
    }  
});

client.on("messageReactionRemove",(reaction,user)=>{
    if(!user) return;
        if(user.bot)return;
            if(!reaction.message.channel.guild) return;
        for(let n in emojiname){
            if(reaction.emoji.name == emojiname[n]){
                let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == rolename[n]);   
            reaction.message.guild.member(user).removeRole(role).catch(console.error);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would suggest to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926998/how-can-i-check-if-the-message-author-has-an-admin-role-using-discord-js / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020854/identifying-admins-from-mentions-discordjs to check if someone is an admin and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045687/check-if-command-is-ran-in-certain-channel for command in certain channel

Comment: not working.. :1

Comment: what is not working? What did you try? you can edit your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58694797/edit)

Comment: changed the code, see... 
if(msg.content.startsWith("reaction" && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() === '
information')){
                                        ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined

Comment: what will be more correct? can you write the correct code in my example code, pls?

Comment: I think you forgot a parenthesis. `f(msg.content.startsWith("reaction" && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() === ' information')){` should be `f(msg.content.startsWith("reaction") && (message.channel.name.toLowerCase() === ' information')){` with the parenthesis closing the "startsWith". Your code seems fine. I can't test it right now, but first try to fix the parenthesis and then if it doesn't work I may able to have some time

Comment: thanks! it working

Comment: No... It seemed.The code functions normally, but on other channels  can still put a reaction, and bot will take off the role.

Comment: wait, why is it `message.channel.name....` and not `msg.channel....` ?

Comment: i dont know, i newbie in dev discord.js bots. Can you write the complete code in the answers that will be correct in your case? on the example of my code

Comment: I can, but not today, I have exam tomorrow and I am working, only checking notification on my pĥone. If you are willing to wait I can help you. Try to do it alone during this time. And yeah it should be `msg` cause it's the variable which contain the message (see the argument of the arrow function  `msg => {...`

Comment: Ok, im wait you =) Good luck with exam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is.
First, be aware that there is 2 types of discord emojis. The unicode one, common emoji, like `➡`. And the guild emoji, that you add to a server.

The first one are represented only by the unicode name, while the second have an id and others difference (see [Emoji](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji) and [Message Reaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction))

That being said, I used the name of the emoji in the `emojiname` array. I then changed a little bit the code to accept both unicode and guild emojis.

The rest of the code was good. Just be sure to use `===` instead of `==` except if you realy want to accept "falsy" term.

[demo gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PZMG.jpg)

```js
// ➡ is an ascii emoji
// lina is a guild emoji
var emojiname = ['➡', 'lina'];
var rolename=["➡ Notifications", "lina supporter"];

client.on('message', msg => {
  if(msg.content.startsWith('reaction') && (msg.channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'information')) {
    for (let n in emojiname){
      let emoji = msg.guild.emojis.find(r => r.name === emojiname[n]);
      if (emoji === null) {
        emoji = emojiname[n];
      }
      msg.react(emoji);
    }
  }
});

client.on("messageReactionAdd",(reaction,user)=>{
  if (!user) { return; }
  if (user.bot) { return; }
  if (reaction.message.channel.name.toLowerCase() !== 'information') { return; }
  for(let n in emojiname){
    if(reaction.emoji.name === emojiname[n]){
      let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === rolename[n]);          
      reaction.message.guild.member(user).addRole(role).catch(console.error);
    }
  }  
});

client.on("messageReactionRemove",(reaction,user)=>{
  if(!user) { return; }
  if(user.bot) { return; }
  if (reaction.message.channel.name.toLowerCase() !== 'information') { return; }
  for(let n in emojiname){
    if(reaction.emoji.name === emojiname[n]){
      let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == rolename[n]);   
      reaction.message.guild.member(user).removeRole(role).catch(console.error);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Eh... I don’t understand, it still works 'crookedly'. I even tried to change to a method through on id. It still works in all channels.
What a lina emoji? [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2yunFAcRs0) <- video from my ds-server with problem

Comment: Sorry to take so much time, but please show how the code should work. Also, in discord not see this emoji '➡'. =/

Comment: Lina is the name of a guild emoji I have on my server (see the comment above the declaration). The arrow emoji is `:arrow_right:` (but you need to give the ascii name). Second the message need to start with "reaction". I thought you wanted this (because of the `startsWith('reaction')`). Then, if you want to use emoji id instead of name (which, you need to change the line ` if(reaction.emoji.name === emojiname[n]){` in both add/remove function, and try `(reaction.emoji.name === emojiname[n]) || (raction.emoji.id === emojiname[n]). And put emoji id in `emojiname`

Comment: But it also responds not only to “reaction” messages, but also to ordinary message with emoji 'bells'. It should work in approximately the following way: [link](https://youtu.be/EOBMOMFL76A)

Comment: in this case just delete the `startsWith` part. I only added it cause you put in your code

Comment: What needs to be set, for messageReactionAdd is executed only in one of the channels? Example, if(**message**.channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'information'), but when setting this function, an error occurs that it cannot determine the 'message.****'.